# A 40L compressed air cylinder at 100 bar is emptied in pulses at the rate of 41kg/s. How many such cycles would it take to empty the cylinder?

Tags: compressed-air, compressors, flow-control, compressed-gases

I am constructing a blowback gas system where clogged debris needs to be removed with compressed air using compressed air cylinder. 40L compressed air cylinder at 100bar pressure is available as standard here. The pressure has to be relieved at the rate of 41kg/s of air in pulses.
Pressure side: Pressure required 64bar, ambient temperature air
Vent side: Pressure 16 bar, ambient temperature air
Pulse duration: 1 sec
How many pulses would it take to empty the tank?/ How many tanks will need for 5 cycles?

Comment: This loks like homework, an assignment or even a test question. You need to show what you have done so far so we can help pointing out errors etc This is NOT a free homework completion service.

Comment: I am constructing a blowback gas system where clogged debris needs to be removed with compressed air I will modify the questions with more data which i've collected

Comment: If you are constructing it, then I recommend an alternate model.  It is very difficult to get a constant mass flow rate with different supply pressures unless you change the downstream load via feedback or secondary containment(usually involves a pressure regulator to keep supply pressure constant) somehow.  As you empty the tank, your supply pressure drops.  Do you have feedback to ensure 41kg/s? What are the conditions required for that feedback (min pressure, etc)?